# Database manager "Loan" out connections to a db

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection-pooling

Trying to roll my own db connection pooling.

```
  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    List<Connection> idleConnections;
    List<Connection> loanedConnections;
    // try to reclaim any previously loaned out connections
    // return a connection from my available pool
    // if there's none enter code here`available, create a new one, add it to my pool, then load it out
  }
```

I know such things exist, like dbcp (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Just wondering if there's a way to "loan objects out" from a manager like that?

Comment: Are you looking for the 'object pool pattern'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Comment: Yes, I guess the "give me a connection" and "here's the connection back" is required in java. Wanted a way to maybe reference count or check when it's being destroyed by garbage collector so I can add it back to my pool instead. The less the user of the database manager has to worry about giving it back to the pool is what I was going for. Thanks for the link, though. Might be the best I can get.